# ActivityTestRule is not imported

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso

I have added below dependencies in gradle:

[image]

But still ActivityTestRule can not be imported, showing error
[image]

Comment: which one android studio version u can use ?

Comment: android studio 3.0.1

Comment: try invalidate caches and restart - its a good cure for lots of common gradle/import issues - may help here.

Comment: Already done that but no luck

Comment: I'm assuming there are no errors when you do a gradle sync, other than the import not being found?  Also you're in the `androidTest` package?

Comment: yes in androidTest package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're using the old dependencies from `Espresso 2.2.2`. For the current version (`Espresso 3.0.2`), the `ActivityTestRule` dependency is found in

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
```

It would probably be a good idea to check [the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/testing-support-library/packages) to make sure that the rest of the dependencies are set up correctly as well, but here's what I'd recommend to get started with Espresso.

**In the `dependencies` section of `app/build.gradle`, add this:**

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
```

**In the `defaultConfig` section of `app/build.gradle`, add this:**

```
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

If you encounter other similar problems, [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/testing-support-library/packages) includes a long list of other gradle dependencies that might have what you need, but what I've listed above should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

**For AndroidX**

> Note: Answer give by Rapunzel Van Winkle is correct and works but androidx we have to use
>   following dependencies,

**Add in app level gradle**

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'
```

Check different dependencies related to AndroidX Test
[official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/set-up-project)